# UWP SyncFusion SfDataGrid Serialization Exception

Tags: serialization, uwp, datagrid, syncfusion

I'm trying to make use of the SfDataGrid component in my UWP app and have everything working just fine in debug mode. When I switched over to release mode to regression test the app before publishing to the Windows store the app throws an exception during grid serialization.

I have an SfDataGrid defined with 4 text columns, 1 numeric column and 1 template column. The template column just includes a delete button so that the user to can remove the row.

I have a method to return the serialization options as follows:

```
private SerializationOptions GetGridSerializationOptions()
{
    return new SerializationOptions
    {
        SerializeFiltering = false,
        SerializeColumns = true,
        SerializeGrouping = true,
        SerializeSorting = true,
        SerializeTableSummaries = true,
        SerializeCaptionSummary = true,
        SerializeGroupSummaries = true,
        SerializeStackedHeaders = true
    };
}
```

Then I have another method to serialize the grid settings as follows:

```
private void RetrieveDefaultGridSettings()
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        gridReport.Serialize(ms, GetGridSerializationOptions());
        _defaultGridSettings = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
    }
}
```

I've followed the SyncFusion documentation (https://help.syncfusion.com/uwp/datagrid/serialization-and-deserialization) which describes how to serialize template columns. I have everything working perfectly in debug mode, but when I switch to release mode I get an exception on this line:

```
gridReport.Serialize(ms, GetGridSerializationOptions());
```

The exception is:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException: 'KnownTypeAttribute attribute on type 'Syncfusion.UI.Xaml.Grid.SerializableGridColumn' specifies a method named 'KnownTypes' to provide known types. Static method 'KnownTypes()' was not found on this type. Ensure that the method exists and is marked as static.'

I've had a look at the SerializableGridColumn class and can see a public static method called KnownTypes so I don't really understand why this exception is happening. I'm even more confused about why it's only happening in release mode.

In attempt to fix the problem I have tried referencing the entire SDK, removing the SDK and referencing the specific assemblies (Syncfusion.SfGrid.UWP, Syncfusion.Data.UWP, Syncfusion.SfInput.UWP, Syncfusion.SfShared.UWP, Syncfusion.SfGridConverter.UWP, Syncfusion.XlsIO.UWP and Syncfusion.Pdf.UWP) but neither yields a different result and the exception still occurs, but only in release mode.

Switching off the setting "Compile with .NET Native tool chain" does resolve the problem, but is not a practical solution as this blocks me from publishing the app to the Windows store.

Thanks very much for any assistance anyone can provide.

Answer (score 0):

After exhausting all possible problems with my own code, I logged with an issue with SyncFusion. They're investigating and will hopefully provide a fix soon.